# swfupload: how to add post parameters before upload starts?

Tags: javascript, swfupload

```
          function uploadStart() {
        swfu.addPostParam("PHPSESSID", "<?php echo session_id(); ?>");
        swfu.addPostParam("photonum", "1");
        swfu.addPostParam("itemid", "<?php echo $row[id]; ?>");
      }
```

OR

```
              function uploadStart() {
        this.addPostParam("PHPSESSID", "<?php echo session_id(); ?>");
        this.addPostParam("photonum", "1");
        this.addPostParam("itemid", "<?php echo $row[id]; ?>");
      }
```

The above code does not work! upload.php script does not receive $_POST[itemid] or any other parameter.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot to set:

```
upload_start_handler : uploadStart
```